# fetch data and sort it without refreshing/reloading the page using ajax/datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, sweetalert2

Problem: I want every time I insert a data and click the okay from the sweetalert popup, the table would automatically fetch the new inserted data and should already be sorted out in
a ascending order.

Solution that I tried:
I tried that every time there's a successful insert it would go down the end of the table, which is not suitable and needs to reload to be sorted and I used .append() to fetch newly data.

I am using DataTables plugin for my table.

My current set up right now is that I had to reload the page every time the data inserted which I think is not good since I am using ajax. I am using a `location.href = "URL"` 
is there any way on how do I refresh the table the page without refreshing the page?

addingUser.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addStudent').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "New student will be added added!",
            icon: "success",
            showCancelButton: true,
            allowEscapeKey : false,
            allowOutsideClick: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
                if(valid){
                    // The studentNumberId should be the basis whether to know if the user is already existing
                    var studentNumberId = $('#studentNumberId').val();
                    var studentFullName = $('#studentFullName').val();
                    var studentPassword = $('#studentPassword').val();
                    var studentEmail = $('#studentEmail').val();
                    var studentYearBlock = $('#studentYearBlock').val();
                        e.preventDefault()
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'includes/model_addStudent.php',
                            data: {studentNumberId: studentNumberId,studentFullName: studentFullName,studentPassword: studentPassword,studentEmail: studentEmail,
                                studentYearBlock: studentYearBlock},
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data === "true"){
                                        // swal if the adding failed.
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        title: "Adding Failed",
                                        text: "Student Already Existing",
                                        icon: "warning"
                                    }).then((result) => {
                                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                          $('#addModalStudent').modal('hide').find("input").val('');
                                        }
                                      });
                                    }
                                else {
                                    // it fetch without reloading but it adds at the bottom and needs to reload the sort the data. Solution that I tried //

                                    /*
                                    $('#tbl_manageStudents').append(`
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>${studentNumberId}</td>
                                    <td>${studentFullName}</td>
                                    <td>${studentEmail}</td>
                                    <td>${studentYearBlock}</td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" name="viewStudents" id="viewStudents" value="View" class="btn btn-info" 
                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewExistingStudents<?php echo $row["ID"];?>
                                        <input type="submit" name="deleteRecord" id="deleteRecord" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" 
                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSelectedStudent<?php echo $row["ID"];?>
                                    </td>
                                    `);
                                    */
                                    // swal if the user was successfully added
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        title: "Successfully Added!",
                                        text: "New student has been added!",
                                        icon: "success"
                                    }).then((result) => {
                                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                            // current set up
                                            location.href = "ManageStudents.php"
                                        $('#addModalStudent').modal('hide').find("input").val('');
                                        // $('#tbl_manageStudents').load("./helper/helper_tblManageStudent.php");

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, thrownError, ajaxOptions){
                                Swal.fire({
                                    title: xhr,
                                    text: thrownError,
                                    icon: "info"
                                })
                            } 
                        });
                }
                else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: "Invalid Form",
                        icon: "warning"
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                Swal.fire(
                'No Changes!',
                'No New Student has been added.',
                'info'
                )
            }
        });   
            });      
    });
```

ManageUsers.php

```
<div class="container-sm table-responsive" id="tblManageStudent">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condense" id="tbl_manageStudents">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Student ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Student Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Student Year and Block</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <!-- Change the tbl to tbl_students -->
                    <?php 
                        include 'helper/helper_tblManageStudent.php';
                    ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

helper_tblManageStudents.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/connection_operation.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students ORDER BY ( 0 + student_id ) ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($query)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['student_email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['student_yrblock']; ?></td>

    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="viewStudents" id="viewStudents" value="View" class="btn btn-info" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewExistingStudents<?php echo $row["ID"];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteRecord" id="deleteRecord" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSelectedStudent<?php echo $row["ID"];?>">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    include './helper/helper_viewExistingStudents.php';
    include './helper/helper_deleteSelectedStudent.php';
        }
    }   
?>
```

is there anyway to reload the table of helper_tblManageStudents.php with the newly inserted data without refreshing the actual page and get the data?

Comment: Approach is wrong. Use the Datatable api to pass the new data to the plugin then do a redraw. If you insert your own html the plugin cache of row html and data knows nothing about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the dataTables API to get data from server through ajax and refresh the data without reloading the page. I create a javascript method that handles loading of data and call this method after creating a record.

1. Inside your view create your table like so

```
    <table id="dataTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

2. Import the [DataTable files](https://datatables.net/download/) including jquery, create the js file and paste this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getData(){
        $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
            'processing':true,
            'destroy':true,
            'order': [],
            'ajax': {
                url: "path/users.php",//path to your server file
                type: 'POST'
            },
            lengthChange: true,
            lengthMenu: [
                [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
                [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
            ]
        });
    }
    getData();
})
</script>
```

3. users.php

```
<?php
    // Create connection to db with server credentials
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    
    $sql = "SELECT name, email, tel FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $output = array('data' => array());

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $name = htmlentities($row["name"]);
            $email = htmlentities($row["email"]);
            $tel = htmlentities($row["tel"]);
            $status = htmlentities($row["status"]);
            
            //EDITED
            $action = "<button class='btn btn-primary'>View User</button> <button class='btn btn-primary'>Delete User</button>";


            $output['data'][] = array(      
                $name,        
                $email,      
                $tel,
                $action //EDITED
            );
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Edited: I have added the buttons to suit your case. All you need to do is to loop over your buttons and concat them.

Comment: Hello, I would like to ask since the users.php has converted to json now, I'm trying to loop the buttons as well i've tried to put it in inside the while loop but it gives me error it gives im a invalid json response. thank you.